# Read more Kafka topics than number of CPU cores

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

From [Spark Streaming Programming Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#points-to-remember-1):

> Extending the logic to running on a cluster, the number of cores allocated to the Spark Streaming application must be more than the number of receivers. Otherwise the system will receive data, but not be able to process it.

Does this mean that if I have 16 CPU cores in the whole Spark cluster I cannot read data from more than 15 Kafka topics?

Comment: Only if you use the consumer based API. This does not apply to Direct Stream one

Comment: @SebastianPiu this should be an answer as it is correct

Comment: Sure, I've added it as an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if you use the consumer/receiver based API. This does not apply to the Direct Stream one.

Have a look [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html) for the differences between the two